# Vertex wont snap to edge

Tags: vertices

[image]

I'm trying to get a vertex of one object to snape to the angled edge of a different object, and even though I have the snap feature turned on, and the snap feature set to edge, the vertex just passes by the edge.  I've tried both including the second object in edit mode (as seen in the gif) and not including it while in edit mode, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.  It's important that the Z location not change, so I'm moving the vertex strictly on the X or Y axis.  Since the edge is angled, there no easy way to know the precise coordinates of where I need the vertex to end up, otherwise I'd just type it in. Same reason I can't set my 3D cursor there.  Lacks the precision I desire, and right now I'm just eyeballing it which is sending my OCD into overdrive.  Please help!

Comment: The GIF is very low quality, try zooming in and recording it. Could you add the blendfile please ? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is select the edge you want to snap the vertex on and then subdivide it, this way you have a new vertex on said edge that you can move to the location you want the snap to happen, then simply snap the two vertices together, and then remove doubles just to be sure you don't have ovelapping vertices.

Answer (score 0):

Snapping (Shift+Tab) works with the same object's edges, as well as with another object's edges. Try to play with an additional option of the snap tool (active, closest, median, center, etc).

Comment: I do not know what you are building, I just have a feeling that you do it wrong way. If you have to deal with such type of snapping, there must be an easy way, like extruding, loop-cutting, using normal transform orientation, etc. Just a thought.